# How to subscribe to pulseaudio events from terminal instead of C?

Tags: bash, pulse-audio

I know that using libpulse one can subscribe to pulseaudio events (volume change, etc.) in a C program. Is there some way that I can achieve this from bash as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `patcl subscribe`.

From the man page:

> ```
>    subscribe
>          Subscribe to events, pactl does not exit by itself, but keeps waiting for new events.
> ```

Sorry for the late reply but I just ran into this myself.